# Mysql join two table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two table in two different database.

1. `Kalix2` -->I have one table `ph_Companies`
2. `Asterisk`--> Here I have table called `cdr`.

In ph_Companies I am having CompanyName column and company name is in this format.

```
   CompanyName
  AccuWebHosting
```

In other table I am having another column clid which stores the company name in the following format.

```
    clid
   "AccuWebHosting-EN" <6618083563>
```

Now, my question is how can I make join between  these two table based on this column. In both the table these are the only column which is having some common data. No other column is having similar data.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    ph_Companies a
        INNER JOIN otherTable b
            ON b.clid LIKE CONCAT('%', a.CompanyName, '%')
```

Caution, this query is very slow if you want large database because it requires a FullTable Scan. The reason is you have "bad" schema design. I'll recommend you to alter the tables like this,

```
CREATE TABLE ph_Companies
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyName VARCHAR(20),
    -- OTHER COLUMNS HERE
);

CREATE TABLE otherTable 
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyID INT,
    CompanyName VARCHAR(20),
    clid VARCHAR(50),
    -- OTHER COLUMNS HERE
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID)
        REFERENCES ph_Companies (ID)
);
```

and you will have a query like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    ph_Companies a
        INNER JOIN otherTable b
            ON a.ID = b.CompanyID
```

which is **FAR** more better than the query above.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the white check mark (*around 15mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)